# How to make clang compile a file only when release?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to make clang compile a file only when release.I work on Xcode. uses Object-c language.
There is a .m file, I just want to compile it into my executable in DEBUG mode, the release mode will not

Comment: Could you please elaborate it in more detail.

Comment: There is a .m file, I just want to compile it into my executable in DEBUG mode, the release mode will not

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way but I have a few alternatives.

A) Multiple targets

B) Use macros.

It would look like the class doesn't exist so could fit your use-case

```
   #if DEBUG

   @implementation XYZ

   @end

   #endif
```

Comment: I don't want to use this way.